# Azure Bastion: Alt Gr key is mistaken for Alt key

Tags: azure, keyboard-layout, azure-bastion

I can't get my Windows Server 2019 Data Center to recognize Alt Gr key when connected to via **Azure Bastion**. The key is mistaken for Alt key. My local OS is Windows 10, my browser is Google Chrome. All other keys are mapped correctly to my hardware keyboard layout.

Anyone familiar with this problem?

KR,
Gerhard

Comment: Same issue over here, but no solution found yet

Comment: Hey @Jordy - seems as if MS just deployed a feature for setting keyboard layout, it solved my problem. Just select your desired keyboard language in the "Connection Settings" section at the Bastion login page in Azure Portal. The selected keyboard language must match the keyboard language of the VM's OS.

Answer (score 0):

I have simply started using the alt + ctrl key combination instead of the Alt Gr key.
So on my Norwegian keyboard the "$" is usually obtained via the ALTGr + 4 button on top, while now I use the left sided alt +  ctrl + 4 to achieve the same result.
This works for any of my ALTgr characters/symbols